# Firefox Close Event from Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

How can I detect when the main Firefox window is closed from an extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to a few different Observer notifications to find that out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications

The one you probably want is quit-application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the SDK's [window](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/windows.html) module and listen for close events, but you'll have to determine which is the main window, since that's arbitrary